Parasols on an Alderson Disk
Parasols on Earth are designed to stop light coming from above, as the sun moves over the sky and its light is more powerful when it is higher in the sky
On an Alderson Disk, the sun is stationary upon the horizon and provides a constant horizontal barrage of light
How could parasols be designed to deal with the Alderson Disk's sun? The parasol must be comfortable enough for a human to easily carry it and turn it around (so as to keep it pointed sunwards as they turn). It needs to provide shade from the sun on the horizon to the majority of a human body. Ideally it should be comfortable for a human to point it in any horizontal direction. The disk has Earth-like gravity that is directly perpendicular to the disk's surface. Materials and manufacture methods can be considered equivalent to modern-day Earth

Whats wrong with a standard parasol/umbrella?  For a larger umbrella, users can rest umbrella shaft on their shoulder. Can therefore handle rain as well.

You don't have the sun bobbing from side to side through the centre?

Inspired by this picture of Assyrian king Ashurbanipal protected by a parasol which has an extension hanging down at the back:

From a central pole you hold in your hands, there are four struts running out in the form of a cross at the top. From two adjecent ends of these struts, there is a lightweight cloth hanging down that blocks the direct sunlight. The other two struts are connected by a chain that acts as a counterweight, balancing the parasol at its center. Just like parasols on earth, you can make the struts collapsable.
A more sophisticated version could have eight struts, with the cloth hanging from four of them. That would make a curved screen, covering a wider angle at a lower diameter.
I especially like that this can be manufactured with Bronze Age technology, maybe even Stone Age (although the existence of collapsable parasols is not proven before the third millenium B.C.)

You're unlikely to need any solar protection living in the earthlike pressure zone of an Alderson Disc, apart from the millions of miles of atmosphere between you and the sun. Alderson Discs, at least the original design, go from the otbit of Mercury out to the orbit of Jupiter with a continuous atmospheric pressure gradient building from near vacuum at the Jovian edge to something humans can deal with around the orbit of Earth. Or possibly from Martian orbit to a little closer than Earth orbit giving a wide band we find habitable and continuing to increase farther in, reaching pressures we find impossible but others, with whom we split the construction cost, find amenable. This puts a sizeable fraction of an AU of air between you and the sun, it's not so much a blinding point of light as a dull orange blob seen through the haze of distance.

A rich person could have a servant carry a parasol to shade the rich person, being rewarded more and punished less the better they do the job.
Or in a society very slightly more advanced than Earth in the year 2024 they could have a personal robot that uses the parasol to keep them shaded.

Harness and solar power
The light source has at least one thing in abundance if there is no night. Light. Instead of just a thin fabric, why not make it solar panels? You'll build a harness that will hold the panels between you and the sun, distributing the weight over your torso. At the same time the motors will automatically angle the solar panels to the sun, allowing minimum effort to keep you in the shade wile keeping your hands free. You'll get used to it quick enough. The power to move it is handily done by the power provided by the solar panels. The aiming is done by a few sensors, which can be (parts of) the solar panels themselves, where an expected amount of electricity helps identify if it is in the optimal position.
I quickly checked what an Alderson Disk is, and it seems you can get some extreme angles from the sun. To still be able to look 'through' the sun screen when walking sunwards, you can add a low voltage camera and a didplay. That way you can still see where you are going.

A harness with a shade attached is closer to a sun-protecting garment than a parasol. It also seems like it would be unnecessarily heavy

What Parasol Users Actually Do

Parasols aren't so common anymore in the West, but in the last century they were quite popular in Europe and America. For those who don't know, a parasol is a very light and relatively delicate piece of kit. Basically a light wooden stick with a bamboo or wood or ivory mechanism for extending the stretchers and ribs. The functional part is a piece of decorated fabric intended to stop light and heat from reaching the user.

Being light in weight, a real parasol can be aimed in any direction. They can be carried over the shoulder, directly upright, or even in the crook of the arm.

(NYPL)

As we can see in the above image, the parasol, carried over the shoulder and aimed a fashionable angle, will be more than sufficient to protect the user from solar rays at the horizon. Note too the bushel basket hat with its deep top and wide brims will also serve as fine protection.

In contradistinction, the parapluie (or umbrella) is a sturdier instrument, often made with a metal stick, stretchers and ribs. The cloth, however, is what distinguishes the two. In this case, the cloth is treated to make it waterproof. Generally speaking, the parapluie is held upright or at a slight angle in order to keep as much rain as possible from striking the head and torso of the carrier.

(avenues.ca)

One often holds an umbrella the same way that parasol is shown in countries where wind is a serious factor in rainfall directionality. I've even held an umbrella directly in front of me before because the rain was more or less horizontal.
